# Extra raise error in admin page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-admin

I have problem in my admin page when I try to edit. In the picture below you can see it ("Field is required" in extra line). When I try to edit I see one extra line. I am little bit customized Membership block with my own form cause I want to show to admin in 'role' field only 'manager' value. It works but edit raise error. By the way when I dont use custom form edit work without problem despite the fact that there are extra line. Here below you can see my code. So I am comfused with that. How can I solve this problem? I also tried to use in form `__init__` this `self.fields['user'].required = False` and `self.fields['role'].required = False` but it didnt help.

**models.py**:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ***FIELDS***
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership',)


ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('developer', 'Developer'),
        ('business_analyst', 'Business analyst'),
        ('system_analysts', 'System analysts'),
)


class Membership (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,)
```

**admin.py**:

```
class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership
    form = MembershipAdminForm
    extra = 1


class MembershipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)

admin.site.register(Project, MembershipAdmin)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class MembershipAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MembershipAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].choices = tuple(choice for choice in ROLE_CHOICES if choice[0] not in ['developer', 'business_analyst', 'system_analysts'])
```

[image]

**ERROR**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1512, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1450, in changeform_view
    self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1031, in save_related
    self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1019, in save_formset
    formset.save()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 651, in save
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 784, in save_new_objects
    self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 928, in save_new
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 539, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]�� ������� �������� �������� NULL � ������� "user_id", ������� "RMS.dbo.project_membership"; � ������� ��������� �������� NULL. ������ � INSERT. (515) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[10/Mar/2017 20:13:34] "POST /ru/admin/project/project/3/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 209512
```

[image]

Comment: use blank=True in your field in model !

Comment: I tried it also but it riase error when try to save. Look my post I update it with full traceback. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: is your models synced?

Answer (score 0):

Add `blank=True` and `null=True` to fields you would like to be optional:

```
class Membership (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I tried it too, but it raise error. Look my post I update it with full traceback. Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: Did you migrate after making the change?

Comment: Sure, I did it.

Comment: Try adding `null=True` to the fields as well

Comment: Its not correct cause everytime when I try to edit I have extra line and empty objects. I update my post with picture. Look it pls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after all I found solution in official documention of Django. In my admin. py file I added `max_num = 1`.

> If the value of max_num is greater than the number of existing related
>   objects, up to extra additional blank forms will be added to the
>   formset, so long as the total number of forms does not exceed max_num

```
class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership
    form = MembershipAdminForm
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1
```